# Intern IE8 WinXP driver won't run

Tags: internet-explorer-8, intern

This is under intern 2 running my own local selenium server.

In IE8 WinXP, I've tried both my own tests which run on IE9/Win7 as well as the intern tutorial. I've tried the geezer branch as well as the regular. Nothing works, they all seem to hang at `Initialised internet explorer 8 on WINDOWS`.

The browser opens and goes to `http://localhost:9000/__intern/client.html?config=tests%2Fintern.js&reporters=webdriver...`
and displays 'Browser Test Runner' as the title. The program seems to freeze indefinitely.

#### Does anyone have a solution for this?

Here is the end of my selenium server log, it seems to get stuck in a loop

```
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.executeScript(EventFiringWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript.call(ExecuteScript.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
22:11:32.783 WARN - Exception: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: host: 'ie8winxp', ip: '10.0.2.15', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: a4381fe3-153c-4072-bb92-e53dbc91e0f4
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=1, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:47261/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
22:11:32.814 INFO - Executing: [get: about:blank])
22:11:33.048 INFO - Done: [get: about:blank]
22:11:33.048 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
22:11:33.064 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return (function getCoverageData() {
        /*global __internCoverage:false */
        return typeof __internCoverage !== 'undefined' && JSON.stringify(__internCoverage);
    }).apply(this, arguments);, []])
22:11:33.080 INFO - Done: [get current url]
22:11:33.126 INFO - Done: [execute script: return (function getCoverageData() {
        /*global __internCoverage:false */
        return typeof __internCoverage !== 'undefined' && JSON.stringify(__internCoverage);
    }).apply(this, arguments);, []]
22:11:33.126 INFO - Executing: [get: http://localhost:9000/__intern/client.html?config=intern.js&reporters=webdriver&baseUrl=%2F&sessionId=761f2175-4b51-4bea-900d-392520d52db8])
22:11:33.345 INFO - Done: [get: http://localhost:9000/__intern/client.html?config=intern.js&reporters=webdriver&baseUrl=%2F&sessionId=761f2175-4b51-4bea-900d-392520d52db8]
```

It "loses" the browser here,

then it gets stuck and prints:

```
22:11:53.892 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
22:11:53.923 INFO - Done: [get current url]
22:11:53.892 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
22:11:53.923 INFO - Done: [get current url]
...
```

over and over again

Comment: Does anything come up in your Selenium log?  Selenium is pretty picky about certain IE settings being in order to minimize the possibility of spurious failures.

Comment: Pasted end of selenium log. Seems to get stuck in a loop.

Comment: Are you running just unit tests, or were some functional tests coming up, too? Have you tried narrowing down which tests are running to see if it's a particular one that's causing the problem?

Comment: It's just a single functional test. It ran fine in IE9/Win7 and I believe IE8/Win7 as well.

I've switched to using the [NightwatchJS](http://nightwatchjs.org) framework instead of Intern as out of the popular choices (webdriver.io, intern, nightwatch), it is the only one that works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I had the same problem recently in IE 10.

In my case, after some investigation, I noticed that IE was in compatibility mode for all websites by default. This was causing JavaScript errors in the tests run by Intern and consequently, hanging all the process.

Flag disabled and everything was running with flying colours.